# Убрать навигацию на предпросмотре в iframe vimeo

Tags: html, iframe, vimeo

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]на сайте стоит встроенное видео с плеера vimeo.

При пред просмотре необходимо убрать контроллеры и все не нужные ссылки на видео,оставив только кнопку Play и что бы все контроллеры появлялись лишь после воспроизведения.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Вимео - это чужая страница в ифрейме, а по соображениям безопасности трогать чужие страницы нельзя.

Не, вы конечно можете написать простенький скрипт, который скроет ненужное в вимео в ифрейме, но вам придется заодно объяснить посетителям вашей страницы, как именно отключить политики запрета в браузере и что именно им придется запускать/задавать вручную.